# ¿Se puede abrir un proyecto ASP.NET en mi Visual Studio que ya ha sido publicado y deployado?

Tags: c#, asp.net, git, github

Buen día.
Los pongo en contexto. La empresa para la que trabajo contrató a un grupo de desarrolladores por un tiempo determinado los cuales desarrollaron una AppWeb. Yo acabo de entrar y tengo todo el peso del mantenimiento y más desarrollo. La primer semana de trabajo, uno de ellos me pasó el código para trabajar en mis cambios, pero no me hizo colaborador en GitHub. Cada quien siguió su desarrollo y ellos hicieron más cambios funcionales al sistema el cual deployaron antes de irse. Sin embargo, una vez que terminaron su contrato ya cualquier cosa que se les pida como repositorios o código me lo están negando. El único recurso que tengo es las carpetas deployadas de la App en la máquina virtual del servidor que contrató la empresa. Necesito subir mis cambios, pero como es código viejo, voy a afectar el funcionamiento de la Web. Entonces la pregunta es... puedo abrir el proyecto que está deployado, en mi visual studio? hay una manera de revertir el proceso que se hace cuando se da en la opción "publicar"?

Comment: No creo que sea fácil pero puedes intentar con un decompilador de los archivos `.dll`

Comment: Tienes que buscar un descompilador, yo una vez ocupe "gray wolf" para descompilar un proyecto en .NET pero era bastante chico

Comment: No me queda claro como la pregunta se relaciona con git.